# How to remove inline object-fit: contain from amp img

Tags: amp-html

I noticed that when AMP converts my `<img>` to `<amp-img><img></amp-img>` it also adds the following inline style to `<img>`

```
object-fit: contain
```

The problem now is that I have the following rule that doesn't work:

```
.slideshow .slide amp-img img {
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

The only thing that can override the inline style is `!important` which gets removed automatically anyways.

Is there any way to get rid of this inline style?

Comment: Hi, have you tried with 'fixed-container' container div as suggested by amp at - https://amp.dev/documentation/examples/style-layout/how_to_support_images_with_unknown_dimensions/?format=websites

Comment: @RohitAmbre Yes, I already tried all layouts. fixed-container removes the entire amp-img for example. Notice that I am letting AMP convert the img to amp-img > img.

Comment: you have to "live with it." We have a problem where `amp-list` causes a line break. Every attempt to override with "keep together" techniques fails. We had to redesign based on that immutable design.